# Custom workflow for document Review and Approval. need suggestion to develop

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, office-365

I want to develop a custom workflow for document Review and approval in Office365 , here are the steps:

1. Create Description:

All employees can be based on a template to create a draft / draft Routine.
in the template, fill in who will review and approve the document. This metadata is then used by the workflow to send the document for review.

2. View Description

The persons appointed as examiners will be notified via email. The notice shall include a link to the workflow where the reviewer can easily perform its task.
The reviewer should be able to send the document:
for approval to another reviewer back to the originator of the document for editing.The reviewer should also be able to interrupt workflow, edit the document, Writing in the associated comment field.

3. Approve Description

Approvers are a group consisting of unit managers and director.
Option 1. When the status of the document released for approved shall be available to all employees.
Option 2. In the SharePoint interface should be easy for users to distinguish the approved documents and unauthorized document.

4. Edit Description

   The reviewer and approver can send the document back to the creator for editing.
   When the creator is finished editing. A new workflow is started for review and approval.

---

By considering above requirements, what is best way to develop this workflow? which approach should i use? Can i develop it in Workflow designer?

Please suggest ?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for also XD